# Javascript - Programmatically animate shapes the same way wiggle paths works in after effects

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, svg

I'm trying to learn more about programmatically drawing and animating shapes using javascript. I'm trying to recreate something like this:

[image: Wiggle Path Animation]

The base shape is a circle which I want to add series of jagged peaks and valleys of various sizes (distortion/zigzags). I also want to add some sliders with [dat.GUI](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) where I can control:

- Points (number of vertices added between existing vertices in the circle. The density of jagged edges.)
- Size (maximum length for segment paths.)
- The speed of the animation.

It similar to how Wiggle Path in after effects works.

**What is the best practice to recreate an animation like in the gif above?**

Is using requestAnimationFrame and drawing on canvas a good solution because it's an "live" animation (not looping)?

Or is using a library like [two.js](https://two.js.org/) to draw SVGs a better solution in this case?

Keep in mind that I want the animation randomly generated over time, and its a learning process where I'm looking for a starting point.

Comment: @Kaiido it's not metaballs. Its simple oscillators per point with complexity 1-3 oscillators moving the points perpendicularly to the line segment they sit on, with the option of smoothing the segments or not. I was hoping OP could post some attempt though..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any code included in the question to address, so here's a general run-through:

The wiggle path in After Effects works by splitting each line segment into several points using interpolation.

```
p = p1 + (p2 - p1) * t;  // t = [0, 1]
// t is a result of length / points, then each segment length / length.
```

Each point is assigned one or several oscillators (the more oscillators the more complex the movement, or put differently: more variations) that starts at a random angle moving the point perpendicularly to the line it sits on. For circles you can see the circle as a single line where interpolation is based on angle instead of distance.

Rotate each oscillator based on temporal phase (speed) and their radius based on spacial phase. Here `Math.sin()` can be used for the y-position of the point along the perpendicular line. For increased complexity you simply add more sin() together each at a different frequency. If you want to normalize the output is up to you.

Connect the points using lines, or to make it smooth like in the example gif, use for example [cardinal splines](https://github.com/epistemex/cardinal-spline-js) which goes through the points and takes n points (disclaimer: the linked solution is MIT, author here).

If you need the shape to start as the same shape each time (like in AE) you will need to implement a custom random function so you can control the seed value at the beginning of the animation.

An alternative to use oscillators is to use Perlin / Simplex noise, but this require you to calculate much more data to obtain the same result.

If you use SVG, canvas or something else doesn't really matter as long as you understand *how* it works and *why* you're using it.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Your solution sounds right, but I'm a bit stuck on understanding the bit when it comes to assigning oscillators. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andauqs2/1/) with what I have now. 

Btw, sorry for not including any code earlier, I just needed to know where to get started. Again, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @lassemt the oscillator can be Math.sin() set to some frequency or arbitrary counter than increments each frame. For more complex behavior just add 2-3 together and normalize. Multiply the result with the radius and use the result for the point's y position (or rather, the perpendicular direction). Do this for all the points at their respective angles - trig-math will be needed.